# Remote file not saving in Komodo while Permission is given to remote file

Tags: permissions, save, editor, komodo

I am trying to access **remote server** while on **local** system using **komodo** editor. I could **access** and **modify** **remote file** but when I saved it, changes does **not** reflect on **remote server**. When I perform save locally on remote file,

It throws the following **error** -

```
There was an error attempting to save file_name.txt :failure
```

I gave **permission** to that file on server to **read, write and execute**.  I'm not able to detect the problem, any suggestion?

Comment: @Der Golem: Please check updated question...

Answer (score 1):

I come up with the same issue with the **KOMODO**, may be this solution can help. I was searching for the issue mean while I try **df -h** command on **remote server**, I saw **/dev/sda1** **size was full**, so I removed unwanted files from same disk and I was able to save the file.

Hope this Help :)